# Multiple java output directories in Eclipse/RAD?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-rad

I'm using RAD (which is based on Eclipse) and I have two `source` folders in a project, one for the core source files, and one the tests.  How can I have them compile to different output (bin) folders?

Obviously I don't want my unit tests to be built into my output jar.

Answer (score 3):

First check the `Allow output folders for source folders` box, then modify the individual `Output folder` elements under each source directory.

[image: RAD/Eclipse Build Path]

<sub>Solution discovered on [EclipseZone](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t83880.rhtml)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the projects, select Properties, then Java Build Path. On the tab "source" you see your source folders. Enable the checkbox "Allow output folders for source folders" and configure each of your source folder appropriate.